# Have I done this integral correctly? $\int x(x^2 + 1)^7 x \,dx$

Tags: integration, substitution

I am used to u-substitution integrals, where all $x$ cancel out, here it does not.

$\int x(x^2 + 1)^7 x \,dx$

Substituting, $u=x^2+1$.

Now, getting $dx$ with respect to $du$,

$\frac{du}{dx}=2x$

$dx=\frac{du}{2x}$

Putting this under the integral sign,

$\int xu^7x \frac{du}{2x}= \frac{1}{2}x\frac{u^8}{8}+c $ (one x now cancels out, one stays)

Now substituting back,

$= \frac{1}{2}x\frac{(x^2+1)^8}{8}+c = \frac{1}{16}x(x^2+1)^8+c$

Comment: Take the derivative of your answer.  (I don't think the problem is stated correctly.  It should have $x^2$ not two $x$'s.)

Comment: Thanks! Also thought about that. Why would the derivative make sense?

Comment: While using substitution technique for integration, You need to make sure that The complete integral is converted to the new substituted variable, you cannot treat $x$ a constant, while integrating with respect to $u$

Comment: Ah, I understand. I think I heard this before somewhere. Is this what is generally referred to as "Feynman's trick"?

Comment: @einzigartigerhummer Uh no, that was a totally different thing. Here Dheeraj is just talking about how u and x are dependent, because you’ve literally defined u out of x.

Comment: Ah, thanks. But could someone please outline, how to do it the correct way (would really be amazing)? In which step should I do the differentiation?

Comment: @einzigartigerhummer Expand your integrandum, you get a polynomial which you can integrate. I don't see an easier solution and neither does integral calculator.

Comment: As commented, you'd just have to expand it all out. But I highly, _highly_ suspect that there's a typo. As @B.Goddard notes, the two $x$'s would normally be combined into an $x^2$ term. But if only one of them was there this would be an easy integral by substitution. Unless the person setting the problem was specifically trying to show that int. by sub. doesn't always work, I'd guess that they meant to write $x$ once, but forgot that they'd written an$x before the paren's, and accidentally repeated it. But we'd need to know more context to be more certain.

Comment: Also, the suggestion to "do a differentiation" is just a way to check your final answer, not a suggestion as part of an integration technique. You asked "is this the correct integral"; the way to check that is to differentiate your answer and see if you get the original function back. You should do it, and see that you _don't_ get your original function back, which shows that there was some mistake.

Comment: This is true, thank you! Substitution without the $x^2$ is pretty easy, else it would need to be expanded.

Comment: Have I written this integral normally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot understand which integral the OP wants to calculate.
Does he want to calculate $\;\displaystyle\int x\left(x^2+1\right)^7\mathrm dx\;\;$ or $\;\displaystyle\int x^2\left(x^2+1\right)^7\mathrm dx\;\;?$

So I will calculate both integrals.

By letting $\;u=x^2+1\;,\;$ we get that $\;\mathrm du=2x\,\mathrm dx\;,\;$ hence ,

$\displaystyle\int\!x\left(x^2\!+\!1\right)^7\!\mathrm dx=\!\!\int\!\dfrac12\,u^7\mathrm du=\dfrac1{16}\,u^8\!+\!C=\dfrac1{16}\left(x^2\!+\!1\right)^8\!\!+C\,.$

$\displaystyle\int x^2\left(x^2+1\right)^7\mathrm dx=\displaystyle\int x^2\sum\limits_{n=0}^7\binom 7nx^{2n}\,\mathrm dx=$
$=\!\!\displaystyle\int\!x^2\!\left(1\!+\!7x^2\!+\!21x^4\!+\!35x^6\!+\!35x^8\!+\!21x^{10}\!+\!7x^{12}\!+\!x^{14}\right)\mathrm dx\!=$

$=\displaystyle\!\!\!\int\!\left(x^2\!+\!7x^4\!+\!21x^6\!+\!35x^8\!+\!35x^{10}\!+\!21x^{12}\!+\!7x^{14}\!+\!x^{16}\right)\mathrm dx\!=$

$=\!\dfrac13x^3\!\!+\!\dfrac75x^5\!\!+\!3x^7\!\!+\!\dfrac{35}9x^9\!\!+\!\dfrac{35}{11}x^{11}\!\!+\!\dfrac{21}{13}x^{13}\!\!+\!\dfrac7{15}x^{15}\!\!+\!\dfrac1{17}x^{17}\!\!+\!C$